# Google Forms - two required questions - accept with at least one of them

Tags: google-forms

I collect links to historical records describing persons falling into certain categories (e.g. secret Protestant or vampire/witch case). User specifies the Category with a checkbox answer (multiple options possible).

I want to add more options, describing professions. But now the checkbox list would be too long.

I want to do either:

1. Add a separate question Profession. One of the the two questions Profession and/or Category must be filled in (required question) or
2. Format the Category question so that the options are organized into sections or the checkboxes appear in multiple columns.

I do not want to add additional form page.

EDIT:
Category explained: It contains information on why that entry is interesting - in general, rare/odd historical cases (e.g. secret Protestant when only Catholicism was permitted). The list may be ~20 options long, which is too much. I could lump some of the options into one category called Profession, but then I need to be able to add another (dependent and required) checkbox list or drop-down to specify which profession of interest it is.

Answer (score -1):

There is a paid plugin for Google forms [Formfacade](https://formfacade.com/website/change-google-forms-layout.html) that can change layout into 2 columns.

Another option would be to [build a form manually](https://medium.com/front-end-augustus-study-notes/custom-google-form-en-f7be4c27a98b) and post the response to the Google form.